# Why is CORS allowed when calling to dummy API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

When I created a WebAPI project, and then a MVC project. In MVC project, I run a sever https://localhost:44303/ which has a page. In this page I created a button for ajax call. I call to my WebAPI project https://localhost:44369/ (different origin), and of course I get CORS policy. I cannot get any data. But when I change the ajax call to a fake API like on the internet https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1, I can get data. I think the fake API and the MVC project have different origin, so CORS should prevent the ajax call. Why can I still get the data from that fake API?

Answer (score -1):

They are simply accepting request from all ip